# Retrieving columns created by user not built in columns

Tags: list, spfield

I want to retrieve columns in `SPList` which are created in the UI not the built in columns, I tried with the `!field.FromBaseType` but it's not working, I tried with the `!field.SourceId.StartsWith("http")`, also not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options avalable to retrieve custom fields

- Check if the field is a built-in field: `SPBuiltInFieldId.Contains(field.Id)`
- Check [SPField.SourceId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.sourceid.aspx)