# CSOM: Identify "columns" created by user rather than built-in

Tags: csom

When iterating the fields of a list how do you know which columns are yours and which are built-in ?

I know a solution for "classic" SDK using SPField.SourceId [(https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95488/retrieving-columns-created-by-user-not-built-in-columns)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95488/retrieving-columns-created-by-user-not-built-in-columns) but **I can't find one for CSOM**. 
I thought UserCreated was the way to go for but [it looks like it's not](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200324/csom-usercreated-and-allowmultiplevalues-properties-are-missing-in-microsoft-sh/200335#200335)

So how do you tell apart theirs and mine ? Using a combination of Hidden CanBeDeleted FromBaseType ? Checking for a list of special internalNames ?

```
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        context.Credentials = creds;
        Web web = context.Web;
        var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

        context.Load(list.Fields);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (Field field in list.Fields)
        {
        bool thisColumnWasCreatedByUser =   
                    field .FromBaseType == false &&
                    //this.InternalName != "Title" && // builtin but I'd rather keep it
                    field .InternalName != "_dlc_DocId" && // probably safe
                    field .InternalName != "_dlc_DocIdUrl" &&
                    field .InternalName != "_dlc_DocIdPersistId" &&
                    field .InternalName != "Combine" && // sucks
                    field .InternalName != "RepairDocument" // sucks too
        }
```

**EDIT**

Mixing suggestions by Viraj Gorajia and Dikesh Gandhi, my current solution is

```
bool thisColumnWasCreatedByUser = 
field .FromBaseType == false &&
(!field .SchemaXml.Contains(" SourceID=\"http")) && // remove "Title", "Combine", "RepairDocument" 
(!field .EntityPropertyName.StartsWith("OData__")) // field .Sealed == true could be working too but I don't know if it could exclude valid results
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving columns created by user not built in columns](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95488/retrieving-columns-created-by-user-not-built-in-columns)

Comment: NO. It is not a duplicate. I already cited this link as not being applicable to CSOM.

Comment: In fact you can get a SourceId (like for a MS.sharepoint.spfield) by parsing SchemaXml (of your  MS.sharepoint.client.spfield)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now this is my best answer

```
bool thisColumnWasCreatedByUser = 
field .FromBaseType == false &&
(!field .SchemaXml.Contains(" SourceID=\"http")) &&
(!field .EntityPropertyName.StartsWith("OData__"))
```

`!field .SchemaXml.Contains(" SourceID=\"http")` will remove "Title", "Combine", "RepairDocument"

`!field .EntityPropertyName.StartsWith("OData__")` will remove "_dlc_DocId",  "_dlc_DocIdUrl", "_dlc_DocIdPersistId"

Answer (score 3):

Set condition as shown below:

```
if(!field.FromBaseType)
{
}
```

Comment: Yes that's a starting point. But I still have built-in columns after that. "Title"
"_dlc_DocId"
"_dlc_DocIdUrl"
"_dlc_DocIdPersistId"
"Combine"
"RepairDocument"

Comment: Try with this condition like if(!field.FromBaseType && field.ShowInEditForm == null)

Comment: There's no ShowInEditForm property but only a  SetShowInEditForm(bool) (which is quite strange by the way)

Comment: Try this one !field.Sealed

Comment: this doesn't filter "Combine" and "RepairDocument"

Comment: "Combine" and "RepairDocument" both are actually inbuilt?

Comment: I think so. They don't follow our naming convention. They look special in the way their sourceid (in .SchemaXml) starts with "http://". And I can find reference of their ids e52012a0-51eb-4c0c-8dfb-9b8a0ebedcb6 , 5d36727b-bcb2-47d2-a231-1f0bc63b7439 (with same names) on the internet so they look like builtin columns to me.

Comment: I don't find "Combine" and "RepairDocument" column in any list or library. If both are hidden, add !field.Hidden in codition.

Comment: I used      !field .SchemaXml.Contains(" SourceID=\"http"). For reference see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/michael_yeager/2008/11/03/reference-list-for-sharepoint-internal-field-names/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!field.SourceId.StartsWith("http://"))
{
   // do your action for completely custom fields
}
```

You will get Url, starting with "http://schemas.microsoft.com" for standard built-in fields.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is for CSOM (Microsoft.sharepoint.client.Field and not Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPField) .  You don't have SourceId on Field. I managed to get one by parsing SchemaXml property. But the filter is still incomplete => this filters out "Title" column (and "RepairDocument" and "Combine") but not _dlc_DocId, _dlc_DocIdUrl, _dlc_DocIdPersistId