# Differentiate between User defined columns and default columns in sharepoint Online using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I want to Differentiate between User defined columns and default columns for a given list  in SharePoint online using CSOM (using  **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client**) . I searched alot but no luck.
 Anyone please suggest how to meet the above requirement or any workarounds.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you interrogate the content type of the list as that should give you the 'default' columns?  Obviously, a list with multiple content types will complicate things.

Comment: Checked  this ? - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200380/csom-identify-columns-created-by-user-rather-than-built-in

Comment: @ Gautam Sheth : your reference links was worked  fine for me.. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is by reading the GROUP of the column if you have a clear separation of custom columns and OOB columns in different groups.
Read the group of a column and match it with OOB groups.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field.group.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712597/retrieve-field-groups-from-sharepoint-csom